# How to combine Count and Min functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to group and count and categorize at the same time.
My table looks like

```
Email_ID     Email_Address      Date
--------     ---------------   --------
1000         a@xxx.com         2018-12-01
1001         b@xxx.com         2018-12-01
1002         c@xxx.com         2018-12-02
1003         d@xxx.com         2018-12-02
1003         d@xxx.com         2018-12-03
1001         b@xxx.com         2018-12-04
1000         a@xxx.com         2018-12-05
1004         d@xxx.com         2018-12-05
```

```
I categorize my Products by email:
```

a@xxx.com and b@xxx.com -> Book
c@xxx.com and d@xxx.com -> Toys

`````
I need to find total number of emails for books and for toys without having duplicate IDs

Here is my code:

```` Select 
    (Select MIN(id) From ticket ti
      Where ti.ID = t.ID) As Customer_ID,
    Case 
        When Email in (a@xxx.com and b@xxx.com) Then 'Book'
        When Email in (c@xxx.com and d@xxx.com) Then 'Toys' 
    End As Product
     From ticket t
     Where

      Date > '2018-12-01' And Date < '2018-12-31'
````
How can I do the count here?
`````

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use simple `count` statement with `distinct`

```
select count(distinct Email_ID) from table1
```

---

```
select ticketId, count(distinct ticket.Email) 
from Ticket
group by TicketId
```

this will give you number of distinct email for each TicketId

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(distinct case when email in (a@xxx.com and b@xxx.com) Then id end) as num_books
       count(distinct case when Email in (c@xxx.com and d@xxx.com) Then id end) as num_toys
from ticket t
where Date >= '2018-12-01' And Date < '2019-01-01';
```